# SAS convert string to datetime18

Tags: datetime, sas, datetime-format

how can I convert a column of string into datetime18. format

example:  '21/01/2020 12:10:20'
desired: 21Jan20:12:10:20

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked out:

```
Data A;  
    Input Text_DT $19.;  
    Datalines;  
21/01/2020 12:10:20  
;  
Run;  

Data B;  
    Set A;  
    DT=DHMS(Input(Scan(Text_Dt,1,' '),DDMMYY10.),Scan(Scan(Text_DT,2,' '),1,':'),Scan(Scan(Text_DT,2,' '),2,':'),Scan(Scan(Text_DT,2,' '),3,':'));  
    Format DT DateTime19.;  
Run;
```

Comment: You can also use TIME informat to convert the HH:MM:SS part into number of seconds.`dhms(input(scan(text_dt,1,' '),ddmmyy10.),0,0,input(scan(text_dt,2,' '),time12.))`